# TurnContext.getConversationReference: Missing Information

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am writing a bot using the botbuilder npm library. I want to use proactive-messages to send notifications to a user, in a personal chat window.

Using the following code to extract conversation-reference:

```js
const conversationRef: Partial<ConversationReference> = TurnContext.getConversationReference(activity);
```

Now, when I try to use the reference object returned above as an argument in the following function:

```js
await adapter.continueConversation(convReference, async turnContext => {
        // If you encounter permission-related errors when sending this message, see
        // https://aka.ms/BotTrustServiceUrl
        await turnContext.sendActivity('This is a proactive notification');
    });
```

I get the following error:

> error TS2741: Property 'name' is missing in type '{ id: string; aadObjectId: string; }' but required in type 'ChannelAccount'.

Is it incorrect to try sending proactive notifications to a personal chat? Or is there a workaround for this.

I am using npm botbuilder V4.10.4

Comment: **UPDATE** - I just added ```@ts-ignore``` statement above ```adapter.continueConversation``` and faced no issues during runtime.

Comment: You need to use Dependency injected dictionary for storing ConversationReference objects used in NotifyController to proactively message users. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet). Could you Please check this code for [proactive message](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Bots/ProactiveBot.cs)? Try if that helps.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT - my issue is not where to store conf-refs, I am storing them in Cosmos. However, in the objects returned by TurnContext.getConversationReference(activity), some fields are missing, which are mandatory according to the Typescript typings file for ConversationReference (the specific fields are mentioned in my question). However, even with those missing fields, the notifications work fine. So I just turned of the Type checking using ts-ignore and it worked fine.